# Hyperledger Fabric - Role of member vs peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, identity

From the official [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/msp.html#identity-classification),

An identity should be classified as

- **client** if it transacts on the network
- **admin** if it handles administrative tasks such as joining a peer to a channel
- **peer** if it endorses or commits transactions
- **orderer** if belongs to an ordering node

So what is the role of a **member** ?

I know **member** is used in specifying policies (`"OR('Org1MSP.member', 'Org2MSP.member')"`) but how does it relate to or differ from a **peer** or **client**?

Answer (score 2):

**member** means you can use any member of an org's MSP,for instance,you can use **admin**,**peer**,**client**.

you can reference https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/endorsement-policies.html#endorsement-policy-syntax

Here are a few examples of valid principals:

- 'Org0.admin': any administrator of the Org0 MSP
- 'Org1.member': any member of the Org1 MSP
- 'Org1.client': any client of the Org1 MSP
- 'Org1.peer': any peer of the Org1 MSP